# Python3 defining room conditions

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

```
def isdark():
    dark = True

dark = isdark()

if dark:
    print('bt')
else:
    print('dasd')
```

Im trying to make it so that it prints `bt` but instead is prints `dasd`, why isn't the `dark = is dark()` condition working?

Comment: The `condition` is working perfectly, your logic is just horribly flawed. The best answer depends on what you are REALLY trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isdark()` is a function with no `return` statement, so it returns None by default. So `dark` never evaluates to true.

You're confusing yourself by using the same variable in two different ways. Here's how I would do it:

```
dark = True
def isdark():
     return dark

if isdark():
    print('bt')
else:
     print('dasd')
```

or more simply:

```
isdark = True

if isdark:
    print('bt')
else:
     print('dasd')
```

or even *more simply*:

```
isdark = True
print('bt' if isdark else 'dasd')
```

Comment: Hee. Of course, in that spirit of reductionism, it could simply be `print "bt"`, too ;)

Comment: Heh, the Pythonista in me always wants to make things as concise as possible. The last example probably isn't practical, as he would likely want to do something more complex than just print out some gibberish in his conditional. But the point is different stuff happens based on the value of `isdark` (which I would assume has the potential to actually be modifed somewhere), which is the spirit of the question

Answer (score 3):

```
def isdark():
     dark = True
```

Here, you are not assigning to the global variable, but creating a local variable and assigning `True` to it. Instead, you can return the value from the function like this

```
def isdark():
     return True
```

Since, you are assigning the returned value to the `dark` variable with this line

```
dark = isdark()
```

whatever you return from `isdark` will be assigned to `dark`.

Apart from that, if you are using that just to check that `if` condition, you can rewrite the code like this

```
if isdark():
    print('bt')
else:
    print('dasd')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return dark, like this:

```
def isdark():
     dark = True
     return dark

dark = isdark()

if dark:
    print('bt')
else:
     print('dasd')
```